# Intermittent Java - MySQL connection Exception | Play Java

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am using Play framework(JAVA) to connect to MYSQL. While interacting with the database, I am getting an intermittent(20% times) the error with exception:

> play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[NullPointerException: null]]   at
>   play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265)
>   ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
>   play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191)
>   ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
>   play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:151)
>   [filters-helpers_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]    at
>   play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:150)
>   [filters-helpers_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]    at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
>   [play-iteratees_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   play.api.mvc.Filter$$anon$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Filters.scala:67)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   play.api.mvc.Filter$$anon$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Filters.scala:61)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$recoverM$1.applyOrElse(Iteratee.scala:629)
>   [play-iteratees_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$recoverM$1.applyOrElse(Iteratee.scala:629)
>   [play-iteratees_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:185)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na] Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:826)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2711)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2847)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ResultSetJavassistProxy.getInt(ResultSetJavassistProxy.java)
>   ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]  at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:61)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:668)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:606)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
>   ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]    at
>   service.UserService.getSessionById(UserService.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
>     at interceptors.SecuredAction.call(SecuredAction.java:26)
>   ~[classes/:na]

The initial cause of this comes from Null pointer exception at

com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:826)

The method in jar is as follows:

```
/**
  802        * Checks if columnIndex is within the number of columns in this result set.
  803        * 
  804        * @param columnIndex
  805        *            the index to check
  806        * 
  807        * @throws SQLException
  808        *             if the index is out of bounds
  809        */
  810       protected final void checkColumnBounds(int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
  811           if ((columnIndex < 1)) {
  812               throw SQLError.createSQLException(Messages.getString(
  813                       "ResultSet.Column_Index_out_of_range_low", new Object[] {
  814                               Constants.integerValueOf(columnIndex),
  815                               Constants.integerValueOf(this.fields.length) }),
  816                       SQLError.SQL_STATE_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT, getExceptionInterceptor()); //$NON-NLS-1$
  817           } else if ((columnIndex > this.fields.length)) {
  818               throw SQLError.createSQLException(Messages.getString(
  819                       "ResultSet.Column_Index_out_of_range_high", new Object[] {
  820                               Constants.integerValueOf(columnIndex),
  821                               Constants.integerValueOf(this.fields.length) }),
  822                       SQLError.SQL_STATE_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT, getExceptionInterceptor()); //$NON-NLS-1$
  823           }
  824   
  825           if (this.profileSql || this.useUsageAdvisor) {
  826               this.columnUsed[columnIndex - 1] = true;
  827           }
  828       }
```

I am not able to figure out what is the cause for the failure since the setup is working perfectly on 80% of the calls.

This error occurs after the

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

which I am trying to figure out separately and if they are related or not, but if the connection is not there and "this" is null, should the code not break much before line 826?

Can anyone please help with identifying the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First I would say to make sure that the MySQL source you are looking at *exactly* matches the driver version you are using.  An NPE on line ``826`` is simply not possible.  Which tells me that the source code does not match the driver version.  Once you find the correct matching source, you'll know a lot more about the failure.  The "Cannot open connection" should be a big red flag.  You may have a leak, or the [MySQL timeout](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server) is shorter than pool configured ``maxLifetime``.