# Occasional NullPointerException in ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds or ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

First of all, please don't close this as duplicate of What is `NullPointerException` and how to fix it. I know what is `NullPointerException`, and I know how to solve it in my own code, but not when it is thrown by **mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar**, which I have no control over.

We encountered the exception when running a common DB query, on a mySQL DB, that works most of the time. We started seeing this exception after deploying a new version, but the query in which it occurs didn't change in a long time.

Here's how the query looks like (with some necessary simplifications). I surrounded it with some of the logic performed before and after. The actual code is not all in a single method, but I put it in a single block to make it easier to understand.

```
Connection conn = ... // the connection is open
...
for (String someID : someIDs) {
    SomeClass sc = null;
    PreparedStatement
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement ("SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H FROM T WHERE A = ?");
    stmt.setString (1, "someID");
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery ();
    if (res.next ()) {
        sc = new SomeClass ();
        sc.setA (res.getString (1));
        sc.setB (res.getString (2));
        sc.setC (res.getString (3));
        sc.setD (res.getString (4));
        sc.setE (res.getString (5));
        sc.setF (res.getInt (6));
        sc.setG (res.getString (7));
        sc.setH (res.getByte (8)); // the exception is thrown here
    }
    stmt.close ();
    conn.commit ();
    if (sc != null) {
        // do some processing that involves loading other records from the
        // DB using the same connection
    }
}
conn.close();
```

`res.getByte(8)` causes a `NullPointerException` with the following call stack :

> com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:763)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5251)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5173)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getByte(ResultSetImpl.java:1650)
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getByte(DelegatingResultSet.java:206)
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getByte(DelegatingResultSet.java:206)

I searched for the source code of the relevant mysql-connector version and found this (taken from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/com/mysql/jdbc/ResultSetImpl.java#ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds%28int%29)):

```
756 protected final void checkColumnBounds(int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
757     synchronized (checkClosed().getConnectionMutex()) {    
758         if ((columnIndex < 1)) {    
759             throw SQLError.createSQLException(    
760                   Messages.getString("ResultSet.Column_Index_out_of_range_low",    
761                   new Object[] { Integer.valueOf(columnIndex), Integer.valueOf(this.fields.length) }), SQLError.SQL_STATE_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT,
762                   getExceptionInterceptor());   
763         } else if ((columnIndex > this.fields.length)) {    
764             throw SQLError.createSQLException(    
765                   Messages.getString("ResultSet.Column_Index_out_of_range_high",    
766                   new Object[] { Integer.valueOf(columnIndex), Integer.valueOf(this.fields.length) }), SQLError.SQL_STATE_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT,   
767                   getExceptionInterceptor());
768         }
769
770         if (this.profileSql || this.useUsageAdvisor) {
771             this.columnUsed[columnIndex - 1] = true;
772         }
773     }
774 }
```

As you can see, the exception occurs on this line :

```
} else if ((columnIndex > this.fields.length)) {
```

which means `this.fields` somehow became `null`.

The closest thing I could find was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834387/intermittent-java-mysql-connection-exception-play-java), which has no answer.

I suspect the issue is not in the query I posted. Perhaps something went wrong with the `Connection` instance due to some other statements we are running on the same connection. All I can say is that we close every statement right after we execute it and read the data from its `ResultSet`.

**EDIT (1/19/2017):**

I couldn't recreate the error in my development environment. I thought it might be some mysql-connector bug triggered when the same connection is used for a long time. I limited the above loop to load at most 6 elements at a time. In addition, we upgraded the mysql-connector version to 5.1.40.

We still see `NullPointerException`s in `ResultSetImpl`, but this time at a different location.

The stack trace is :

> com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5294)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5151)
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:198)
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:198)

which implies this time the exception was thrown as a result of one of our `res.getString()` calls (I don't know which one).

I found the source for **mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar** [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/ResultSetImpl.java#L5294) and the relevant code is:

```
5292            // Handles timezone conversion and zero-date behavior
5293
5294            if (checkDateTypes && !this.connection.getNoDatetimeStringSync()) {
5295                switch (metadata.getSQLType()) {
```

which implies `this.connection` is null. `this.connection` is an instance variable of type `MySQLConnection`, which gets initialized in the constructors of `ResultSetImpl` and is only set to null when `public void realClose(boolean calledExplicitly)` is called (it is called by `public void close()`, which, according to the documentation within the source, is called when `ResultSet.close()` is called). We are definitely not closing the `ResultSet` prior to reading all the data from it.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Do you use apache dbcp? In which version? Can you update that version? Have you searched for a bugreport/issue under https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&pid=12310469&sorter/field=issuekey&sorter/order=DESC&status=1&status=3&status=4 ?

Can you update MySQL Conector to version 6.0.x ? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: @TobiasOtto I don't know what "apache dbcp" is. The queries run under apache tomcat 8.0.28. I can't update it, but if I'll be able to prove this is an issue fixed by that version, I can convince the person responsible for deployment to update it.

Comment: @TobiasOtto I Googled the exception I got, and didn't find anything helpful yet.

Comment: Hi @Eran, I googled the last line of your stacktrace and thougt that you use that library.That was just a guess. Maybe you can explain how do you receive/create the connection to the database?

Comment: Does the exception always occur on `getByte` ? Also what happens if you change the order you retrieve the fields (e.g putting `getByte(8)` as the first statement) ?

Comment: @Berger The problem is it only happened in production and I can't recreate it locally. Therefore I can't make that test.

Comment: @TobiasOtto It is created with - `Context jndi = new InitialContext (); DataSource ds = jndi.lookup ("java:comp/env/jdbc/DBName"); Connection conn = ds.getConnection();` where "jdbc/DBName" is a resource defined in a config file - tomcat-dir\conf\Catalina\host\filename.xml

Comment: @Berger so far I've only seen one log of this exception, so I can't say. I was told it happened multiple times.

Comment: Just in case, could you post the full stack trace (sometimes the NPE just tells that the resulset was closed, and is not the real root cause : https://sourceforge.net/p/c3p0/bugs/7/) ? Maybe you could use JMeter to simulate high activity, by the way there is something maybe similar here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385845/jdcbc-connection-error-with-jmeter-test

Comment: @Berger The rest of the stack trace only contains the call chain of our production code. I can't post that, and it doesn't seem relevant to me.

Comment: Have you considered trying a more recent version (eg 5.1.40), because I do see some NullPointerException fixes in the [changelogs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1.html)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I guess we will advance to the latest version at some point, though the descriptions of the NullPointerException fixes in these changelogs don't seem related to my situation. Thanks for the link.

Comment: There was one that piqued my interest in 5.1.39, but I couldn't quickly find the bug to see if it was really similar (the id in the changelog doesn't seem to match the MySQL bug db...)

Comment: Below line throwing the exception: 

  if (checkDateTypes && !this.connection.getNoDatetimeStringSync()) {

but this.connection has been called by line 5268 too and there was no exception, so my suspicion is connection closed from somewhere else, maybe multiple queries access same data source or your container has a pooling strategy but if it is so you shouldnt get this exception at always same line of the code

Comment: @HRgiger From what I see line 5268 passes `this.connection` to `this.thisRow.getString()`, which checks if the connection is null before using it, so it wouldn't throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Oh yes if it is null it returns StringUtils.toAsciiString

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has been a long time since I posted this question, and I want to post an answer that describes the exact scenario that led to this tricky `NullPointerException`.

I think this may help future readers who encounter such a confusing exception think outside the box, since I had almost every reason to suspect this was a mysql connector bug, even though it wasn't after all.

While investigating this exception I was sure that my application can't possibly be closing the DB connection while trying to read data from it, since my DB connections are not shared across threads, and if the same thread closed the connection and then tried to access it, a different exception should have been thrown (some `SQLException`). That was the main reason I suspected a mysql connector bug.

It turned out that **there were two threads accessing the same connection** after all. The reason this was hard to figure out was that **one of these threads was a garbage collector thread**.

Going back to the code I posted:

```
Connection conn = ... // the connection is open
...
for (String someID : someIDs) {
    SomeClass sc = null;
    PreparedStatement
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement ("SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H FROM T WHERE A = ?");
    stmt.setString (1, "someID");
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery ();
    if (res.next ()) {
        sc = new SomeClass ();
        sc.setA (res.getString (1));
        sc.setB (res.getString (2));
        sc.setC (res.getString (3));
        sc.setD (res.getString (4));
        sc.setE (res.getString (5));
        sc.setF (res.getInt (6));
        sc.setG (res.getString (7));
        sc.setH (res.getByte (8)); // the exception is thrown here
    }
    stmt.close ();
    conn.commit ();
    if (sc != null) {
        // do some processing that involves loading other records from the
        // DB using the same connection
    }
}
conn.close();
```

The problem lies in the "do some processing that involves loading other records from the DB using the same connection" section, which, unfortunately, I didn't include in my original question, since I didn't think the problem was there.

Zooming into that section, we have:

```
if (sc != null) {
    ...
    someMethod (conn);
    ...
}
```

And `someMethod` looks like this:

```
public void someMethod (Connection conn) 
{
    ...
    SomeOtherClass instance = new SomeOtherClass (conn);
    ...
}
```

`SomeOtherClass` looks like this (of course I'm simplifying here):

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    Connection conn;

    public SomeOtherClass (Connection conn) 
    {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable
    { 
        if (this.conn != null)
            conn.close();
    }

}
```

`SomeOtherClass` may create its own DB connection in some scenarios, but can accept an existing connection in other scenarios, like the one we have here.

As you can see, That section contains a call to `someMethod` that accepts the open connection as argument. `someMethod` passes the connection to a local instance of `SomeOtherClass`. `SomeOtherClass` had a `finalize` method which closes the connection.

Now, after `someMethod` returns, `instance` becomes eligible for garbage collection. When it is garbage collected, its `finalize` method is called by the garbage collector thread, which closes the connection.

Now we get back to the for loop, which continues to execute SELECT statements using the same connection which may be closed any time by the garbage collector thread.

If the garbage collector thread happens to close the connection while the application thread is in the middle of some mysql connector method that relies on the connection to be open, a `NullPointerException` may occur.

Removing the `finalize` method solved the issue.

We don't often override the `finalize` method in our classes, which made it very difficult to locate the bug.

Answer (score 2):

> The only way this could be happening, as far as I can see, is
>   someone/something is calling ResultSet.close() right after
>   ResultSet.getString() has been called, but before it returns.
>
> This could be your application (is it multi-threaded, or does it have
>   a tricky processing path), or you could be losing the connection
>   sometime during this time, which causes the driver to close the
>   connection implicitly, which closes all open statements, which closes
>   all open result sets.
>
> You shouldn't be getting an NPE though, we should raise a nicer
>   SQLException.
>
> You might check the mysqld error log to see if anything is going on
>   there that implies that the connection is being lost?

-- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41484

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This may describe something similar to our problem, though we use a newer version of mysql connector, and we see different stack trace than those shown in that link (our NPE occurs in a different location), which is almost 7 years old. I agree that this is most likely a bug of mysql connector, and SQLException should be thrown instead of NPE. However, this doesn't help us avoid that bug. We do have a multi-threaded application, but each thread obtains its own DB connection from Tomcat, so the same connection shouldn't be used by multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: Actually, it seems you were probably right. We found a place that might close the connection `right after ResultSet.getString() has been called, but before it returns`. It's hard to re-create, since it requires a specific timing, but once we deploy a fix, I believe we will stop seeing NPEs. I'll post more details once we confirm the problem is fixed. It's not a mysql connector bug after all.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you would have posted full stack trace.

It can be a concurrency issue if rs is a class variable where two threads are sharing your Resultset and executing it simultaneously for different queries.

One way to proceed on this is to use debugger with break point way before exception occurs and step through to notice where this happens. Put a breakpoint in a must use sql connector code too like connection.createStatement(...) or inside api, if it is a multithreading issue debugger will  jump to it where you may analyse further by looking at call stack.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in other answers, the root cause of `NullPointerException` is that `ResultSet` instance is getting closed. Below could be the possible reasons:

- Explicit close of result set by calling `rs.close()`. (it does not seems applicable here, as in above code `rs.close()` not called).
- Implicit close of result set. A result set can get closed implicitly by JDBC driver in some scenarios like:

  - If same `PreparedStatement` object is shared by multiple threads concurrently. Re-execution of query would implicitly close the previously opened `ResultSet`.

[Assuming your query is getting executed concurrently], It seems connection.preapresStatement is returning same statement object (*incorrectly*) when called concurrently.

What I can suggest you to try disabling the prepare statement cache (via `cachePrepStmts` connection property) and see if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I can't proof that this is the right explanation, but even if it is not it might point in some good direction.

It all comes down to figure out how [com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/com/mysql/jdbc/ResultSetImpl.java) `fields` protected member variable could have taken a `null` value.

If I have followed the stack trace properly, ResultSetImpl is instantiated by calling static [ResultSetImpl.getInstance()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/com/mysql/jdbc/ResultSetImpl.java#ResultSetImpl.getInstance%28java.lang.String%2Ccom.mysql.jdbc.Field%5B%5D%2Ccom.mysql.jdbc.RowData%2Ccom.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection%2Ccom.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl%2Cboolean%29) which is called by [com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.buildResultSetWithRows()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java#MysqlIO.buildResultSetWithRows%28com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl%2Cjava.lang.String%2Ccom.mysql.jdbc.Field%5B%5D%2Ccom.mysql.jdbc.RowData%2Cint%2Cint%2Cboolean%29) which is called by [MysqlIO.getResultSet()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java#MysqlIO.getResultSet%28com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl%2Clong%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cboolean%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%2Ccom.mysql.jdbc.Field%5B%5D%29)
Inside getResultSet() we find that first `fields` initialized to `null`

```
Field[] fields = null;
```

then it does

```
if (metadataFromCache == null) {
    fields = new Field[(int) columnCount];
    ...
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        skipPacket();
    }
}
```

Let's assume that `metadataFromCache != null` therefore `fields` won't be set to a non `null` value.
Then let's assume that

```
this.connection.versionMeetsMinimum(5, 0, 2) &&
this.connection.getUseCursorFetch() &&
isBinaryEncoded &&
callingStatement != null &&
callingStatement.getFetchSize() != 0 &&
callingStatement.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
```

is `true` and `usingCursor` is also `true` which is to say that `versionMeetsMinimum(5, 0, 5) && (this.serverStatus & SERVER_STATUS_CURSOR_EXISTS) != 0` is also `true`
then when calling

```
ResultSetImpl rs = buildResultSetWithRows(callingStatement, catalog, fields, rows, resultSetType, resultSetConcurrency, isBinaryEncoded)
```

fields will be `null`.

This could cause the `ResultSetImpl` to get a `null` value in its `fields` and it is compatible with it happening after you upgraded from a version prior to 5.0.5 to 5.1.36.

The bad news is that I can't see how `isBinaryEncoded` takes value true and this is another necessary condition for the `ResultSetImpl` instance to be created with a `null` fields.

If this conjecture is correct then the bug is a missing `(metadataFromCache == null) ? fields : metadataFromCache` at `MysqlIO.getResultSet()` and changing the `ResultSet` type from `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` to `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` might prevent the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: `it is compatible with it happening after you upgraded from a version prior to 5.0.5 to 5.1.36` - The only recent upgrade we did was from 5.1.36 to 5.1.40. Prior to the upgrade we had `NullPointerException` in `ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds` and after the upgrade we had `NullPointerException` in `ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal`. Your detailed analysis (which I appreciate) only relates to the former exception, which we no longer get after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

As for now to avoid multiple iteration and keeping Connection longer open. you can user IN query instead of single id in iteration.

```
Connection conn = ... // the connection is open
...
    SomeClass sc = null;
    PreparedStatement
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement ("SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H FROM T WHERE A in (?)"); 
//here you need to concate String to form like ('a','b')
        stmt.setString (1, someID);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery ();
        if (res.next ()) {
            sc = new SomeClass ();
            sc.setA (res.getString (1));
            sc.setB (res.getString (2));
            sc.setC (res.getString (3));
            sc.setD (res.getString (4));
            sc.setE (res.getString (5));
            sc.setF (res.getInt (6));
            sc.setG (res.getString (7));
            sc.setH (res.getByte (8)); 
        }
        stmt.close ();
        conn.commit ();
        if (sc != null) {
            // do some processing that involves loading other records from the
            // DB using the same connection
        }

    conn.close();
```

Also IN query allows you only 1000 ids so if it is more than than then you need to split in equal amount of list. I think you can give a try for this. It should resolve.

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help, since after we load the `SomeClass` instances, we still have to perform some additional processing that involves loading other records from other tables (that's what I referred to in the "do some processing that involves loading other records from the DB using the same connection" comment), so we can't close the connection immediately even if we load all the `SomeClass` instances using a single statement.

Comment: I am not sure exactly how much data set you are playing with. There is two different instance where you encountered nullpointer so i believe may be we are overheading on connection and statement that cant be handled by mysql jar itself. so may be we try to tweak our query to give less overhead for procesing. just you can give a try where you are facing this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Could you rewrite your code to use one try-catch-block?
Then you would have the connection inside the method and no one else could close the connection.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class StackProblem1
{
    void dbQuery(final String[] someIDs)
    {
        try (final Connection conn = getConnection();
             final PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                 "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H FROM T WHERE A = ?"))
        {
            for (final String someID : someIDs)
            {
                stmt.setString(1, "someID");
                final ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
                if (res.next())
                {
                    final SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
                    sc.set(res.getString(1));
                    sc.set(res.getString(2));
                    sc.set(res.getString(3));
                    sc.set(res.getString(4));
                    sc.set(res.getString(5));
                    sc.set(res.getInt(6));
                    sc.set(res.getString(7));
                    sc.set(res.getByte(8)); // the exception is thrown here
                    // do some processing that involves loading other records from the
                    // DB using the same connection
                }
            }
        }
        catch (final SQLException sqlEx)
        {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the connection is open
     */
    private Connection getConnection()
    {
        return null;//FIXME return connection
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that (in my real code I'm passing the connection to a rather large method that uses it to perform other queries), but I'm sure the connection is not closed elsewhere. Otherwise this code will always fail.

Comment: @Eran Yes that life :-( Maybe the problem with your code is not passing the connection from one method to another, but that you pass it in a loop with an open resultset? I would read out one resultset after another and then - after closing the resultset and the statement - pass the connection to the next method.

Comment: We pass the connection after the Statement (and therefore the ResultSet) are closed. Each iteration of this loop creates a new statement. The statement I posted is actually encapsulated within a method. A snippet closer to the actual code would be - `for (String someID : someIDs) {
    SomeClass sc = loadSomeClass(someID); conn.commit();if (sc != null) {*do stuff, including additional DB queries*}}`